# Segmentation Fault When Traversing Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in C. I believe I am creating and inserting elements correctly, but there is a segmentation fault every time I try to loop through. Here is my code for the linked list:

```
struct node {
char **data;
struct node *next;
};
```

Two global variables to store pointers to head and tail:

```
struct node *head;
struct node *tail;
```

Code to insert an element:

```
void insert(char **args)
{
    struct node* pointer = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    pointer -> data = args;
    pointer -> next = NULL;
    if( head == NULL ) {
            head = pointer;
            tail = pointer;
    }
    else {
            tail -> next = pointer;
            tail = pointer;
    }
}
```

I then try to go through the list and print the data contents (this successfully prints the elements in the list, but then there is a segmentation fault):

```
int print_list(char **args)
{
    struct node *curPointer = head;
    if(curPointer == NULL) {
            printf("%s", "List is empty\n");
    }
    else {
            printf("%s", "List: ");
            do {
                    int i;
                    while(curPointer->data[i] != NULL) {
                            printf("%s", tail->data[i]);
                            i++;
                    }
                    printf("%s", "\n");
                    curPointer = curPointer->next;
            }while(curPointer->next != NULL);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Other functions in my program that rely on looping through the list have a similar segmentation fault issue.

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger to help you find the problem.

Comment: Warning: The argument `char **data` isn't used in function `insert()`

Comment: In function `insert`, you declare argument `data`, but in the body you use `args`, which is presumably undefined.  It seems the code you posted differs significantly from what you're trying to debug.  Fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The value of local variable `i` having automatic storage duration is used without initializing, so it will invoke *undefined behavior*. Initialize `i` by replacing `int i;` to `int i = 0;`
- When `curPointer` becomes `NULL` in `curPointer = curPointer->next;`, dereferencing `curPointer` in the condition `curPointer->next != NULL` have a big chance to cause Segmentation Fault.
  Try using `curPointer != NULL` instead of `curPointer->next != NULL` for the condition.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!